# Unable to connect using Htmlunit to website using HTTPS

Tags: java, ssl, https, htmlunit, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to use HtmlUnit to log in to a website that uses a HTTPS connection and I get an error caused by the statement

```
page = webClient.getPage(url);
```

The exception is

```
error:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
```

What I have done so far:

- Exported the individual certificates in the website's certificate chain using Firefox and imported them into the JVM's default keystore using the java keytool, for example:

  ```
  keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Certificates\VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.crt -keystore C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\security\cacerts
  ```
- Started a new keystore using the java keytool, and imported only the relevant root, intermediate, and specific website's certificate.
- Set this certificate as the java certificate store using

  ```
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Users/Henry/workspace/AutoEtime/cacerts");
  ```
- Tried changing the browser version to Chrome and then to Firefox
- Tried to use SSLPoke.class from confluence.atlassian.com to test if the certificates were correct, however I don't know the port to connect to, and using the default 433 gives a `ConnectException: Connection timed out`

I have not tried using any of the other methods outlined in the `WebClientOptions` documentation found [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html), because I am not sure how to use them to get the effect I want.

One of the most common answers that I have seen online is the suggestion to use `webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);`

This works fine for testing my application, however I need to have the connection be secured using SSL because of the sensitivity of the username and passwords that I am using to connect to the website.

One interesting thing I want to add is that **one out of every 5-10 attempts actually works**, and does not throw the SSLHandshakeException, even though I have changed nothing in the code.

How do I fix this problem? Additionally, why does it work every once in a while?

Comment: The default port for HTTPS is 443 not 433. Manually changing/writing files on Windows under `\Program Files` or `\Program Files (x86)` is a bad idea; for newish Windows versions such changes may not work or may work only sometimes, which _might_ explain your intermittent behavior. Either install Java elsewhere (I like `c:\Java`) or use your second bullet: create your own keystore and point to it; you should only need the root cert(s) if the server behaves correctly, and make sure to set `trustStore` (AND `trustStorePassword` if not `changeit`) before the FIRST use of SSL in the JVM process.

Comment: Is it possible that you provide the hostname you try against?

Comment: You were right Dave, I had typed the port in wrong in both my question and as an argument when running SSLPoke.class. As soon as I changed it and added the certs, it successfully connected.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured it out by just trying different things. It turns out that I needed to import the certificates in .der form instead of .crt. The default keystore already had the correct root certificate, but what it was missing was some combination of the intermediate and leaf certificate. After I imported intermediate.der and leaf.der and specified where my copy of the cacerts file was the SSLHandshakeException hasn't happened again. Hopefully this has actually fixed it and that exception is gone for good.

Comment: Henry Mahar I don't understand your answer here. What is a der? How did you find them? We have a similar issue.